# Can connect to share on windows server, but access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

I can connect to a share on a 2k3 server, but I get an access denied error when I try to open the share.

What I have done so far:

1. Created a new group in AD
2. Granted the group full access to the folder I want to share.
3. Created a share for that folder, restricted to the new group.

Share settings:

[image]

Filesystem settings:

[image]

If I do

```
net use x: \\server\shared-folder /USER:domain\username
```

I get a connection and I can see the share connected in explorer.

If I try to open the share I get an access denied error.

What's missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely to have the file permission not set correctly at the NTFS level.
A share can have some specifics permissions while the file system may have differents.

You can change the ntfs permission by using the folder or file properties on the explorer.

Let us know how it worked.

Comment: I added the configuration I've done for the file system and the share. Is there anyhting more I have to do?

Comment: Oh, that's a shame I can not read german.
However, in Windows you have to types of permission. One is NTFS, which means even if the connection is local the permissions will apply. Another is Sharing permission which sets few information. It is common to quite open Sharing permission while making the restrictions in the NTFS panel.

Comment: Edit: By the way, are your users into the AD group?

Comment: Yes, I added myself, logged out and in again.

Comment: You could use the tool to check the permission applied to your account. Be careful that any Forbids will take precedence over any authorise. So if you are part of a group that is denied, you will never be able to be granted again, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks, I was just doing this. I don't have access rights on NTFS level. But I cannot find any entry that denies any access to this folder.

Comment: And can you find any entry that allows you?
You could try to add yourself, and not the group, in order to see if you can access. Thereafter you can start deeper investigations.